# How to prevent Path manipulation issues in C#

Tags: path-manipulation

How to prevent Path manipulation issues in C#
For below statment getting error.

EX:

File.Exist()

File.Create()

File.Delete()

File.OpenRead()

File.OpenWrite()
.